# Grabbing Tree from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, mvvm, extjs6

My hope is to get a JSON object rendered as a tree in my view. My code is in a file called /app/view/main/Tree.js

```
Ext.define('SGSS.view.main.Tree', {    
   extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
   alias: 'viewmodel.tree',
   xtype: 'SimpleTree',
   width: 400,
   height: 250,
   store: {
       root: {
           expanded: true
       },
       proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: '/cgi-bin/uiconnector',
           reader: {
               type: 'json',
               rootProperty: 'assets'
           }
       }
   }
});
```

When I call upon the page that references this, I get a screen that looks a little different than intended:

[image]
It's just blank folders that will go on indefinitely. Not the JSON object that I had in mind. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "assets": {
    "batteryzone": [
  {
        "id": "10001",
        "type": "batteryzone",
        "label": "BZ1",
        "parentid": "1001",
        "model": "sim",
        "alarmsev": "None",
        "extant": "true",
        "invertersonline": "0",
        "hvaconline": "0",
        "racksonline": "0",
        "interfacerev": "0",
        "plcrevision": "0",
        "numbatteryracks": "20",
        "dcvoltage": "0.0",
        "dcpower": "0.0",
        "averagesoc": "0.0",
        "storedenergy": "0.0",
        "startupsubstate": "0",
        "startupsequence": "0",
        "recoverymode": "false",
        "tempmaxconnected": "-4.0",
        "chargecapacity": "0",
        "dischargecapacity": "0",
        "dccurrent": "0.0",
        "containerenabled": "false",
        "hicell": "3.016",
        "locell": "3.011",
        "nameplateenergy": "1950",
        "recoveryrunning": "false",
        "currinputs": []
  },
  {
        "id": "10002",
        "type": "batteryzone",
        "label": "BZ2",
        "parentid": "1001",
        "model": "sim",
        "alarmsev": "None",
        "extant": "true",
        "invertersonline": "0",
        "hvaconline": "0",
        "racksonline": "0",
        "interfacerev": "0",
        "plcrevision": "0",
        "numbatteryracks": "20",
        "dcvoltage": "0.0",
        "dcpower": "0.0",
        "averagesoc": "0.0",
        "storedenergy": "0.0",
        "startupsubstate": "0",
        "startupsequence": "0",
        "recoverymode": "false",
        "tempmaxconnected": "-4.0",
        "chargecapacity": "0",
        "dischargecapacity": "0",
        "dccurrent": "0.0",
        "containerenabled": "false",
        "hicell": "3.016",
        "locell": "3.011",
        "nameplateenergy": "1950",
        "recoveryrunning": "false",
        "currinputs": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? (I mean, obviously I am!)

Comment: The first issue I see is that your store seems to be defined not as a TreeStore, but rather as a standard (flat) store. I had the same indefinite-recursion issue more than once when I forgot to make the store a tree store.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON format which you are using is not the correct tree format that tree panel needs to form a tree. The data format required is shown here:

```
       {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: 'SFO  &nbsp;✈&nbsp; DFW',
                duration: '6h 55m',
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: 'SFO &nbsp;✈&nbsp; PHX',
                    duration: '2h 04m',
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'PHX layover',
                    duration: '2h 36m',
                    isLayover: true,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: 'PHX &nbsp;✈&nbsp; DFW',
                    duration: '2h 15m',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
```

Here the rootProperty to be specified is **'children'** as stated in the [docs for the treestore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) in the following section:

> Reading Nested Data
>
> For the tree to read nested data, the Ext.data.reader.Reader must be
>   configured with a root property, so the reader can find nested data
>   for each node (if a root is not specified, it will default to
>   'children'). This will tell the tree to look for any nested tree nodes
>   by the same keyword, i.e., 'children'. If a root is specified in the
>   config make sure that any nested nodes with children have the same
>   name.

Also note that **leaf: true** has been used to represent that node to be the terminal / leaf node of the tree, i.e., that node doesn't contain child nodes.

You can refer the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) for more examples on the data format.

Comment: Wow... so this tells me that ExtJS6 **cannot** use JSON as is? I have to add these values to JSON somehow in order to make it usable?

Comment: Yes the data needs to be formatted to suit the tree data structure.